# how to add listview in tab fragment

Tags: android

I created three fragments to show on my main activity. This is one of the three fragment activity :

```
public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    String[] values=new String[]{"India", "java", "c++","Ad.Java", "Linux", "Unix"};
    public Fragment1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.center, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

I want to show a listView in this fragment. I tried to use this code inside `onCreateView()` method :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but it shows error.. How to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried ListFragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this code ill help u..

```
   String[] values=new String[]{"India", "java", "c++","Ad.Java", "Linux", "Unix"};
   ListView lv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.center, container, false);
perform(v);

    return v;
}

public void perform(View v) {
lv = (ListView)v.findViewById("your view id");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Comment: still it is showing error in the line findViewById as "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"