# Can't make listview work with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have 3 tabs, on one of them i have a listview for contact details which can't make it work.

The listview is inside the fragment layout with id *list*. And i'm getting this error when trying to access that tab:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2 at com.gabrielfiocchi.packemovilvq.ListaParaTabContacto.getView(ListaParaTabContacto.java:42)`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908100/how-to-add-listview-in-tab-fragment) worked, but not with this custom adapter.

The code below:

**TabContacto.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TabContacto extends Fragment{

String[] web = {
        "Correo",
        "Twitter",
        "Teléfono"
} ;
String[] datos = {
        "info@somemail.com",
        "@sometwitter",
        "+0123456789"
} ;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.img_mail,
        R.drawable.img_twitter,
};

ListView lv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacto, container, false);
    perform(v);
    return v;
}

public void perform(View v) {
    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ListaParaTabContacto adapter = new ListaParaTabContacto(getActivity(), web, datos, imageId);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

And this is my custom adapter: **ListaParaTabContacto**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListaParaTabContacto extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final String[] datos;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public ListaParaTabContacto(Activity context,
                                String[] web, String[] datos, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.datos = datos;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        txtTitle2.setText(datos[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `imageId` array has only 2 values.

The third parameter of `ArrayAdapter` constructor is the elements to be shown in the `ListView`. So based on `web` array, there are 3 elements in the `Adapter`.

When the `ListView` construct's the last element, `position = 2`, you access the `imageId` array with an invalid position, throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You must add one more item to `imageId` or remove any element of `web` array (the `ListView` will have 2 elements) or check if `position < imageId.length` before access its position.

Comment: Silly of me if that's the problem. I'll try it out and come back to post results. Thanks Wakim.